# How to set the Time delay in the properties of timer event in Drools rule flow

Tags: timer, drools, drools-flow

I am trying to use the timer event in Rule flow file of Drools(jbpmn)
I set the value of the "time delay" property as "10s". But nothing is happening. The script after the timer event is not even executing once.
Can anyone help me on this. I have just started working on drools..

Comment: Could you share the process definition and screenshot? Are you starting your process? Are you sure the execution reaches the timer event node? Or are you using a catch event to start a flow?

Regards,

Comment: I cannot share the screen shot as I am new to this site.
Yes I am starting my process. If I remove the timer node from the .bpmn file then the script runs. But if I add a timer event before the script then nothing happens. Neither any exception or error.
Can you tell how to configure timer node in the rule flow file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have set the timer properties? It is not enough to put the timer on the diagram. You also need to configure the timer using, for example, the Bpmn2 Diagram Editor.